# Overriding a material CSS class in Angular component CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have overridden some global material styles in an Angular component CSS file (not scss) like so:

```
.fixed-plugin .dropdown-menu {   
   left: -503px !important;
   width: 500px;
}
```

This does work, however, it affects all references to these CSS classes in the component which is fine where is only one reference.

What I would really like to do is somehow create my own class and somehow inherit from the `fixed-plugin .dropdown-menu` and then apply my overrides (change widths). Then I can reference my own class in the only place I need it and the global material CSS remains untouched.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your component styles use this `:host ::ng-deep .dropdown-menu`. It limits styles to your component and overrides global angular styles for your components inside.